# Nodes won't reconnect to seed

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remoting

We have three nodes in different AWS data centers, one of which is the sole seed node and exclusive possessor of a singleton, accomplished by using `.withDataCenter` on the singleton proxy settings. We can get our cluster to work as-designed by starting the seed node and then the others, but if any of the nodes go down it seems the only way to get them talking again is to restart the whole cluster in the same way. We'd like to get these to try to reconnect to the seed node and resume normal operation when they can.

When I take down a non-seed node, the seed node marks it as UNREACHABLE and begins to periodically log the following:

`Association with remote system [akka.tcp://application@xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://application@xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx]] Caused by: [connection timed out: /xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx]`

Fair enough. When I bring the node back up, however, the newly-started node begins to repeat:

`2018-01-29 22:59:09,587 [DEBUG]: akka.cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18 - 
now supervising Actor[akka://application/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-16#-1572745962]`

`2018-01-29 22:59:09,587 [DEBUG]: akka.cluster.JoinSeedNodeProcess in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - 
started (akka.cluster.JoinSeedNodeProcess@2ae57537)`

`2018-01-29 22:59:09,755 [DEBUG]: akka.cluster.JoinSeedNodeProcess in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 - 
stopped`

The seed node logs:

`2018-01-29 22:56:25,442 [INFO ]: a.c.Cluster(akka://application) in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 - 
Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@52.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx] dc [asia] - New incarnation of existing member [Member(address = akka.tcp://application@172.xx.x.xxx:xxxx, dataCenter = indonesia, status = Up)] is trying to join. Existing will be removed from the cluster and then new member will be allowed to join.`

`2018-01-29 22:56:25,443 [INFO ]: a.c.Cluster(akka://application) in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18 - 
Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@52.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx] dc [asia] - Marking unreachable node [akka.tcp://application@172.xx.x.xxx:xxxx] as [Down]`

and repeatedly thereafter:

`2018-01-29 22:57:41,659 [INFO ]: a.c.Cluster(akka://application) in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18 - 
Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@52.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx] dc [asia] - Sending InitJoinAck message from node [akka.tcp://application@52.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx] to [Actor[akka.tcp://application@172.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-8#-1322646338]]`

`2018-01-29 22:57:41,827 [INFO ]: a.c.Cluster(akka://application) in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18 - 
Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@52.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx] dc [asia] - New incarnation of existing member [Member(address = akka.tcp://application@172.xx.x.xxx:xxxx, dataCenter = indonesia, status = Down)] is trying to join. Existing will be removed from the cluster and then new member will be allowed to join.`

It seems strange to me that the log indicates things "will" happen that don't, the existing being removed and the new member being allowed to join. I've been googling that message and can't find an explanation of what I may need to do to make that actually happen.

Comment: The multi-dc feature of Akka allows you to have multiple dc-local clusters that are part of a bigger cluster, with one leader per dc, this means that running a three node cluster where each node is a separate dc (and therefore leader in its own sub cluster) does not make much sense. Not sure if this relates to your issue, but be aware that the regular recommendations to have at least 3 nodes in a cluster applies also for these sub clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that you're on Akka.NET, it looks like you might've hit on an [open issue](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3252), in which the leader keeps trying to remove the old incarnation to let the new incarnation join.  There were some troubleshooting suggestions in the issue ticket about relaxing `heartbeat-interval` that may perhaps provide some insight into possible causes.

Given the generally higher latency across multiple geographically dispersed datacenters, an area I would look closely into is [failure detection](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-dc.html#failure-detection).

This may not seem relevant to the reported problem, but based on your displayed logs it appears that there were time discrepancies between the two nodes in different datacenters.